# Python library to compute std dev of vectors

Tags: python, standard-deviation

I have three feature vectors as :

```
A = [1,0,1,0,0,0]
B = [0,0,0,1,1,1]
C = [1,1,1,0,1,0]
```

Is there a python library that can help me compute the std dev of these ?

Comment: Well in case if you want to stick to Pure Python and you can use Python 3.4+ then can try the [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module from the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.std`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) for population standard deviation:

```
>>> [numpy.std(arr) for arr in (A, B, C)]
[0.47140452079103168, 0.5, 0.47140452079103168]
```

---

However, if you want to stick to built-in modules (and have Python v3.4+), you could check out the functions `pstdev` and `stdev` in the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module to calcultae population standard deviation and sample standard deviation respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = [1,0,1,0,0,0]
>>> B = [0,0,0,1,1,1]
>>> C = [1,1,1,0,1,0]
>>> numpy.std(map(numpy.mean,zip(A,B,C)))
0.16666666666666666
>>> map(numpy.mean,zip(A,B,C))
[0.66666666666666663, 0.33333333333333331, 0.66666666666666663, 0.33333333333333331, 0.66666666666666663, 0.33333333333333331]
```

Comment: I want to compute std dev over three feature vectors A,B and C: that is mean = [ A1+B1+C1/3 , A2+B2+C2/3 , A3+B3+C3/3 ... ]

Comment: Still not sure that I understand - did you mean stdev(average(A,B,C))??